# BottomNavigationBar with page view wont animated to indexed page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I try to add three pages on BottomNavigationBar to navigate to the indexed page, the impimention of my code is so clean with no errors but the BottomNavigationBar wont change to other pages meanwile the selecten BottomNavigationBar item color changes to the selected one with no any errors on DEBUG console and this is my code

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int bottomSelectedIndex = 0;

  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> buildBottomNavBarItems() {
    return [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
          title: new Text('Red')
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
        title: new Text('Blue'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
          title: Text('Yellow')
      )
    ];
  }

  PageController pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
    keepPage: true,
  );

  Widget buildPageView() {
    return PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        pageChanged(index);
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        Red(),
        Blue(),
        Yellow(),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void pageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void bottomTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
      pageController.animateToPage(index, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: buildPageView(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: bottomSelectedIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          bottomTapped(index);
        },
        items: buildBottomNavBarItems(),
      ),
    );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `PageView.builder` 
code snippet

```
List<Widget> listWidget = [Red(), Yellow(), Blue()];
...
return PageView.builder(
      controller: pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        pageChanged(index);
      },
      itemCount: listWidget.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return listWidget[index];
      },
    );
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> listWidget = [Red(), Yellow(), Blue()];
  int bottomSelectedIndex = 0;

  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> buildBottomNavBarItems() {
    return [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.home), title: new Text('Red')),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
        title: new Text('Blue'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline), title: Text('Yellow'))
    ];
  }

  PageController pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
    keepPage: true,
  );

  Widget buildPageView() {
    return PageView.builder(
      controller: pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        pageChanged(index);
      },
      itemCount: listWidget.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return listWidget[index];
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void pageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void bottomTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
      pageController.animateToPage(index,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: buildPageView(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: bottomSelectedIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          bottomTapped(index);
        },
        items: buildBottomNavBarItems(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Red extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Red");
  }
}

class Blue extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Blue");
  }
}

class Yellow extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Yellow");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it looks like I have a problem with my flutter  SDK content, still have the same problem even when I use your code

Comment: @chunhunghan would you know how to convert this code to Cupertino iOS?